# Java Jackson: Deserialize JSON with dynamic Names into JavaClass

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, spring-resttemplate

I'm trying to deserialize JSON using jackson. The problem is that field names always change.

Here is an example JSON:

```
{
 2021-08-02: [
   {
      label: "OnlineGallery",
      nb_uniq_visitors: 1,
      nb_visits: 2,
      nb_events: 2,
      nb_events_with_value: 0,
      sum_event_value: 0,
      min_event_value: 0,
      max_event_value: 0,
      avg_event_value: 0,
      segment: "eventCategory==OnlineGallery",
      idsubdatatable: 1
   }
 ],
 2021-08-03: [ ],
 2021-08-04: [ ]
}
```

I´m getting the data by Resttemplate and try to deserialize into Java Class but it doesn't work:

```
private EventsGetCategory getEventFromAPI(Date startdate, Date enddate) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

    ResponseEntity<EventsGetCategory> response =
        restTemplate.getForEntity(
            matomoUrl + "index.php?module=API&label=OnlineGallery&method=Events.getCategory&secondaryDimension=eventAction&idSite=1&period=day&date=" + dateFormat.format(startdate) + "," + dateFormat.format(enddate) + "&format=JSON&filter_limit=-1"
                + "&token_auth=" + tokenAuth,
            EventsGetCategory.class);

    return response.getBody();
  }
```

**EventsGetCategory Class:**

```
@Data
public class EventsGetCategory {

  @JsonAnySetter
  private Map<String, List<EventDetails>> details;

}
```

**EventDetails Class:**

```
@Data
public class EventDetails {

  String label;
  int nb_uniq_visitors;
  int nb_visits;
  int nb_events;
  int nb_events_with_value;
  int sum_event_value;
  int min_event_value;
  int max_event_value;
  int avg_event_value;
  String segment;
  int idsubdatatable;

}
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Your `EventsGetCategory` class like this

```
public class EventsGetCategory {
    private Map<String, List<EventDetails>> details;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setDetails(String key, List<EventDetails> val) {
        if (this.details == null) {
            this.details = new HashMap<>();
        }
        this.details.put(key, val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the field names are always changed then you can not use a class like EventDetails to map the JSON object to a java class, instead of EventDetails class, you have to use Map<String, Object> where you can store dynamic key values.